# How to show $\operatorname{GL}_2 (\mathbb Z_2)\cong D_3$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to show that $\operatorname{GL}_2 (\mathbb Z_2)\cong D_3$ while $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ is the group of matrices $2\times 2$ above $\mathbb Z_2$.
I tried to show that maybe every $A\in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z_2) $ is a rotation or reflection, but I failed to do that.

Comment: One silly way of doing it would be to find the order of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$, then to prove that it is not abelian. Can you see why this works?

Comment: You mean $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ above?

Comment: I do. I've edited it.

Comment: Isomorphism does not mean equality. You can't show the elements of this matrix group are rotations or reflections. As an analogy, even though the exponential function is an isomorphism from $\mathbf R$ to $\mathbf R_{>0}$, it does not mean you will find elements of the second group that are negative just because some elements of the first group are negative. An isomorphism means the underlying groups have the same structure, but not that every *interpretation* of the meaning of an element in one group will carry over to an element of the second group.

Comment: @user1729 well both are of order 6 and non abelian. but i cant see it.. hint?  is there only one group of that sort up to isomorphism?

Comment: @sha Exactly! I've given a (hopefully) more helpful answer now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on the space $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, and it fixes the origin. The remaining 3 points are permuted, and every permutation is realised (prove it!). This means that $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has $S_3$ as a homomorphic image, but as both groups have order 6 we have that $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong S_3$.

Finally, label the points of your triangle with $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and use a similar argument to see that $D_3\cong S_3$. Hence, $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong D_3$.